# Having trouble creating this Form in the GUI Builder

Tags: codenameone

I have this picture of a Form that I want to re-create in Codename One UI design, but I'm stuck at separating the two buttons by a white line. See image below to give me an idea of how to achieve this:

[image: Form to be recr-eated]

Comment: please provide examples and don't provide links to external sites. also if you have a moment please read the documentation for guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this type of design, you will have to extract the text/buttons from the background image. Follow these steps:

1. Remove **Cather** and **Gifter** buttons with their slogan from the background.
2. Add the background image to your `theme.res` and create a custom form uiid which will have background image scaled to fill.
3. Set your form's layout to `GridLayout` with 2 rows and 1 column.
4. Add 2 containers to your form (top and bottom) and set their Layouts to `new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER)`.
5. Inside each container, add another container with layout set as `BoxLayout.y()`.
6. Inside this final BoxLayout containers, that's where you will add  **Cather** and **Gifter** buttons with their slogans as Labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !